# How to Restrict creation of objects from certain class

Tags: c++, inheritance, private-constructor

I have a 'Bank' class and a 'Branch' class. 'Branch' is inherited from 'Bank'. I want to allow ONLY 'Bank' object to  create new 'Branch' objects. (e.g. only citi group can open new branches of citi banks).

What is the best design pattern to achieve this?

I am currently using friend class with private constructor. but I am not sure whether it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to do this, It would make it harder to write tests for `Branch`? Perhaps what you want is simply to make the `Branch` constructor take a `Bank` as an argument?

Comment: yes testing will be harder.. but then any code can assign any branch to any bank.. that is what i wish to restrict.

Comment: There is a conceptual issue in the design, a *Branch* is not a *Bank*, it is just a *branch* of that particular *bank*

Answer (score 2):

> 'Branch' is inherited from 'Bank'

There's your problem, you're using inheritance. You're looking for an abstract factory pattern, where the `Bank` is the branch creator, and provide access to constructor of branches only to their respective creators.

```
struct Branch  //abstract
{
    virtual ~Branch() = 0;
};
class CitiBranch : Branch
{
    friend class Citi; //only Citi can create instances of CityBranch
private:
    CitiBranch();
};

struct Bank
{
    virtual ~Bank() = 0;
    virtual Branch* createBranch() = 0;
}

struct Citi : Bank
{
    virtual Branch* creatBranch()
    {
        return new CityBranch;
    }
}
```

This programs to an interface rather than a concrete class. So you have `Branch` pointers and `Bank` pointers, and don't really need to know their exact type.

If you have a `Bank*` and call `createBranch()`, you'll get a `Branch*` back but it will point to a correct concrete object.

Comment: this will work. I am also using similar pattern friend and private constructor. I used inheritance too because 'Branch' shares many attributes of 'Bank' such as logo, mission statement...

Comment: @apostopher that's unnecessary information duplication, because you'd have lots of branches with the same info. I'd just keep that info in the Bank class and have it accessible to the branches, not inherit it.

Comment: ya that's a nice idea. Also I agree with @ DavidRodríguez. so inheritance is wrong here..

Comment: @apostopher well, even if you go with a different design, inheritance is **clearly wrong**. A branch is definitely not a bank.